# Python: Output issues using while loop

Tags: python, loops, math, while-loop

I am trying to figure out how to output the variables/functions of their solutions and their differences.

I was having issues with it infinitely outputting the same thing, so I put a break it in. But now I'm confused about how to print everything in one line (if that makes sense?)

Edit: (thank you @dgg32)
updated

```
import math
def my_sqrt(a):
    x=5
    y=1
    while True:
        y = (x + a/x) / 2.0
        if y == x:
            break
        x = y 
    return y 
def test_sqrt():
    a=5
    while True:
        if a<=25:
            b=my_sqrt(a)
            c=math.sqrt(a)
            d=abs(b-c)
            print (f"a={a} | my_sqrt(a)={b} | math.sqrt(a)={c} | diff={d}")
            a=+1

test_sqrt()
```

it should output the name of the variables with their values (using 'a' up to 25. So, 25 total output lines showing the value of 'a' the calculation of my_sqrt, math.sqrt, and the difference between them.

Right now, it is endlessly outputing the same result with no incremental updating like I would have expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your question is about how to print concat message?

In your print statement you quoted the whole expression, python will print the whole thing without change.

You can: 1. concat quote and variable, 2. f-string or 3. formated output. I find f-string the easiest:

```
value = 3
print (f"a is {value}")
```

output:

```
a is 3
```

In your case, just add a letter "f" in front of the quote should do the trick:

```
    print (f'a = {b}  | my_sqrt(a) = {b} | math.sqrt(a) = {c} | diff = {d}')
```

Comment: thank you so much. I was stuck on that part. Now I'm left with the issue of 'a' not updating itself +1 until 25 (it just endlessly loops at the same spot)

```python
import math
def my_sqrt(a):
    x=5
    y=1
    while True:
        y = (x + a/x) / 2.0
        if y == x:
            break
        x = y 
    return y 
def test_sqrt():
    a=5
    while True:
        if a<=25:
            b=my_sqrt(a)
            c=math.sqrt(a)
            d=abs(b-c)
            print (f"a={a} | my_sqrt(a)={b} | math.sqrt(a)={c} | diff={d}")
            a=+1

test_sqrt()
```

Comment: To avoid infinite loop, first figure out the stop condition and write it in the "while" statement, avoid both "break" and "while True". In both of your cases, "while true" can be both avoided. For the first instance, consider "while x != y". Second instance, "while a < 25". Afaik, "while True" is only a must in multithreading and multiprocess to keep the daemon alive.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a while loop, you need to have a criteria for it to stop iteration otherwise it continues to infinity. You can either use a for loop that ends at 25 or whatever number is needed or use a while loop with variable that will be used to terminate the loop. You created an infinite loop and it breaks after producing one iteration.

```
count = 0
while (count < 9):
   print 'The count is:', count
   count = count + 1
```

Second, break tells python to exit the loop entirely. If you use a break it will tell python to stop running the loop.

If you want to format a string for printing a stylish output, you need to use string formatting where you either use format() or the newer f-strings

```
"Hello, {}. You are {}.".format(name, age)
'Hello, Eric. You are 74.'

name = "Bob" 
'Hello, {}'.format(name)
'Hello, Bob'

name = "Eric"
age = 74
f"Hello, {name}. You are {age}."
'Hello, Eric. You are 74.'
```